# Helicon ISAPI Rewrite + ASP.NET : How to remove . aspx extension?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

How do i remove .aspx extension like:

http://www.foo.com/bar --> http://www.foo.com/bar.aspx
http://www.foo.com/bar?q=boo --> http://www.foo.com/bar.aspx?q=boo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.\?]+)/?(\?.*)?$ /$1.aspx$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of ISAPI_Rewrite you are using - 2 or 3.

The v3 syntax is:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /$1.aspx [L]
```